# How to go back in ex mode from vi?

Tags: bash, vim, vi, ex

I'm learning vi/vim. Recently, I've faced with some uncertain point. When I run:

```
ex somefile
```

The ex editor opens. Ok, good. After some play I run:

```
:vi
```

Now I'm in normal vi mode. Everything is clear here. But the question is:
**How can I go back to ex mode** (the first time I run `ex filename` from bash)? I've tried [shift]+[q] (hence Q), but nothing happens.

Comment: are you in normal mode when you try `Q`? it should just work

Comment: Does `:map Q` return anything?

Comment: Running `:map Q` returns just `Q` symbol at the bottom line (I run it just after `vi somfile`)

Comment: Following the manual `:ex` does the trick. I guess you are expect the existing output will disappear from screen (which seems not the case). Try `:help visual`

Comment: try `gq` from normal mode. refer : `:help ex-mode`

Comment: Yes I guess.. I've read it, but what's next? I found `:ex` is the same as `:edit` so it shouldn't go me back in "ex mode" I expect.

Comment: @user4668401 yahhoo! `gQ` does what I need! `:help ex-mode` was very helpful! Post it as the answer - I accept it.

Comment: Check my previous comment. You solve my problem)

Comment: Using ex seems trendy.

Comment: @romainl, do you think so?))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say  what version of vim you were using, but the help (:help ex-mode) does say this:

> Note: In older versions of Vim "Q" formatted text,
>                           that is now done with gq.  But if you use the
>                           vimrc_example.vim script "Q" works like "gq".

So you could try <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> in normal mode or help also says

> gQ                      Switch to "Ex" mode like with "Q", but really behave
>                           like typing ":" commands after another.

In that case you could try <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> from normal mode.

Comment: `gq` doesn't work as expected. So add a note to try `gQ` (hence [G],[shift]+[Q]) instead `gq`.

Comment: Do you know how come back to ex-mode by typing command after colon? Something like `:ex-mode` instead pressing keystrokes like `gq`.

Comment: If I type `:ex` vim tells me I need to specify a file. So I would try that, otherwise sorry I dont know

Comment: If I type `:ex <filename>` then it works for me. out of interest what is it about `:ex` mode that makes you so keen to use it?

Comment: Sorry, I've only come back from study..So, nothing special about being keen on `ex`. I just want to learn a little about vi and ex))